# Integral homology of infinite real projective space

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Can you provide a reference for the computation of the infinite-dimensional real projective space, defined using its standard CW structure?

Comment: I think in the book of Hatcher he has done it with using the degree concept.

Answer (score 2):

For $\mathbb{R}P^n$, this is Example 2.42 on page 144 of [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).  As far as I can tell Hatcher doesn't explicitly mention the case of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ (though he does later when talking about cohomology on pages 220-222), but it works exactly the same way (the cellular chain complex just continues infinitely).